# Invoke several Jupyter Notebook sequentially through bash scripting while needing parameters

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to invoke 6 jupyter notebooks through command line, each script requires the same set of parameters that should be invoked through the command line as well.

I've been able to test jupyter nbconvert on dummy scripts that dont have parameters and that works fine. Now, the next step is being able to sequentially run scripts that require the same parameters but I dont know how to incorporate the parameters in

EDIT:
So right now the code looks like this-
I tested it on scripts that just printed an output. But if I make the scripts require parameters for a function, how would I approach that

```
#!/bin/bash
notebooks=("notebook1.ipynb" "notebook2.ipynb" "notebook3.ipynb")

for nb in "${notebooks[@]}";do
 jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute "$nb" --output "$nb"
    echo "Running $nb"
done
```

Comment: So what you need is a bash script that accepts an arbitrary amount of variables and then runs the same command with the same parameters only on a different file each time?

Comment: I don't see a script in your question. It is hard to suggest how to incorporate something into something invisible. I suggest that you post at least what you are doing when for all 6 notebooks, when you want to invoke them manually.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you tagged this _bash_   **and** _python_. First make up your mind, whether you are looking for a bash program or a python program, and use only one tag.

Comment: Also, I think the _invoke_ tag does not make sense. According to the tag description, the meaning is _Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle_. If this is indeed relevant to your question, please explain in what way it is.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. I'm just not sure how to incorporate the variables in

Comment: Please finish editing in your existing command... prefix each line with 4 spaces to make it show as code.

Comment: @Wentee Do you mean that the notebooks variable needs to change by command like `notebooks=("notebook1.ipynb" "notebook2.ipynb" "notebook3.ipynb")` one time and ``notebooks=("notebook4.ipynb" "notebook5.ipynb")` the next or do you mean that they need to get parameters of their own? If so do the parameters change between scripts or are the consistent between the scripts in a call?

Comment: no, the notebook variables remain the same. The notebooks contain functions in them that require parameters. The parameters will be consistent in all the scripts

Comment: So why not hard code them in the for loop like so: `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute "$nb" --output "$nb" --param a --param b...`? Or put them in a const in the beginning of the shell script?

Comment: when I try that, there's an unrecognised flag error

Comment: Please add an example of that and the error you get to your question.

Comment: [NbConvertApp] CRITICAL l Bad config encountered during initialisation:
[NbConvertApp] CRITICAL l Unrecognised flag: '--param'

Comment: For parameters you can use [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill). Or you can use a Python or bash script and have placeholders in the text. Then you can make a version with the substitutions substitued using Python's string replace, for example. Then execute the new version from a command with `jupyter nbconvert` or [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html), which adds some nice features. nbformat can also be useful for building the notebook pre-execution using pieces and substitutions.

Comment: There's also a similar discussion of options passing the parameters [here](https://felixchenier.uqam.ca/a-very-simple-way-to-pass-inputs-to-jupyter-nbconvert-to-automate-reports/).

Comment: cant seem to pip install papermill on work laptop unfortunately, thank you for the resource though